# Hashing Password with "$2y$" identifier

Tags: c#, uwp, moodle

```
String strAlgName = HashAlgorithmNames.Sha1;

HashAlgorithmProvider objAlgProv = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(strAlgName);
CryptographicHash objHash = objAlgProv.CreateHash();

String strMsg1 = "test";
IBuffer buffMsg1 = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(strMsg1, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf16BE);

objHash.Append(buffMsg1);

IBuffer buffHash1 = objHash.GetValueAndReset();
```

I have codes like this above, they are working fine but I'm gonna use them for moodle project, so I need to hash my passwords with "2y$" identifier.

What can I use? I can't use nuGetPackages like cryptsharpofficial, cause it gives error when I want to use it in Windows 10 November Update (10586)

Comment: `$2y$` is the `crypt` scheme ID for a variant of bcrypt/blowfish - look for a C# library that supports this, .e.g https://github.com/BcryptNet/bcrypt.net

Comment: Moodle is a php project, and it stores passwords with password_hash command. If I want to add data in mysql, I need to use "2y$" identifier. Otherwise passwords doesn't work. 
and does "bcrypt.net" supports 10586 update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just installed "BCrypt.Net-Next" and codes shown in below works well:

```
string hashedPassword = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(passToHash);
```

Thanks to @iainn, his comment link:
[Hashing Password with "$2y$" identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49878948/hashing-password-with-2y-identifier#comment86773692_49878948)

Comment: 2023: `BCrypt.Net-Next` will generate `$2a$` hash. Not `2y` but `2a`. Doesnt work with things like [`.htpasswd`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/misc/password_encryptions.html). [See drewmerk answer for correct solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75114685/628532).

Answer (score 2):

The `BCrypt.Net-Next` by default uses the `$2a$` algorithm.

You can have it explicitly use `$2y$` by specifying the `bcryptMinorRevision` of the `GenerateSalt()` function like this:

```
string salt = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.GenerateSalt(8, 'y');
string hashedPassword = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(passToHash, salt);
```

Here are the first few lines of the decompiled `GenerateSalt()` function from that library:

```
        public static string GenerateSalt(int workFactor, char bcryptMinorRevision = 'a')
        {
            if (workFactor < 4 || workFactor > 31)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("workFactor", workFactor, $"The work factor must be between {(short)4} and {(short)31} (inclusive)");
            }

            if (bcryptMinorRevision != 'a' && bcryptMinorRevision != 'b' && bcryptMinorRevision != 'x' && bcryptMinorRevision != 'y')
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("BCrypt Revision should be a, b, x or y", "bcryptMinorRevision");
            }
```